# Path to remote storage in Django / Apache application

Tags: django, apache, azure-storage, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to access to file / directories on a remote storage, in a Django Application. My webserver is Apache, and both virtual machine and storage are hosted by Windows Azure.

I want to do it both from Python and encapsulated C++ code, by example creating an empty file in Python.

```
open("\\\\samples.file.core.windows.net\\share\\file.ext","a").close()
```

(see this link for the path :  https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage).

When using this path under Apache, it fails with IOError :

```
invalid mode ('a') or filename: '\\\\\\\\digitalstructurestorage.file.core.windows.net/
```

Adding http and https as prefix does't help, when not escaping the slashes, it writes the file on the C: drive of the virtual machine.

```
open("\\samples.file.core.windows.net\\share\\file.ext","a").close()
```

However, when connecting in RDP to my virtual machine, I can successfully write the file when launching a Python script. I believe there's something to add in Apache / MOD_Wsgi configuration to correct this behaviour, but I could not found documentation about it.

I also precise that I've to provide path as input to some functions of 3rd party librairies, that's why I'd like to avoid Windows Azure API or any higher level API to manage the Input/Output.

Thx in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to use Azure File Storage on your Azure VM like using local filesystem. So firstly you need to mount a share directory of Azure File Storage on your VM OS, please refer to the offical tutorial for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) to do it. Then, you can do these file operations in Python normally like on local without Azure Storage SDK.

If you just want to store files using Azure Storage, it seems to be not a good choice for using Azure File Storage. I suggest using Azure Blob Storage for your Django App, and you only follow the third-party plugin `django-storage` introduce for Azure to configure it for your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I had followed the tutorial, without any success. I solved my problem meanwhile : the problem was that APACHE server was not "aware" of the mounted share because it runs with user system. I had to run powershell with user SYSTEM with psexec to solve it. https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Comment: @user3790252 Great! Thanks for sharing your solution.